# Database Design Ideas/Feedback

Tags: database, database-design, nosql

I have made many relational database designs before, and think I am experienced in some of these design patterns...however, I cannot think of quite where to start for this problem.

I am creating a database of gyms, that will have basic gym information in a 'Gyms' Table.

Then I will have another table called 'Equipment' which is a list of possible equipment that any gym can have, such as "Bench", "Box", "Weight Plate", etc.

Then I have a table for GymsEquipment, which is a list of: GymId, EquipmentId, Available.

```
GYMS
-----------------
id   Name    Units
1    Gym A   Imperial
2    Gym B   Imperial
3    Gym C   Metric

EQUIPMENT
-----------------
id   Name
1    Bench
2    Box
3    Weight Plate
4    Dumbbells

GYM EQUIPMENT
-----------------
id   GymId    EquipmentId    Available
1    1        1              1
2    1        2              0
3    1        3              1
4    2        1              0
5    2        2              1
6    2        3              1
```

That's all quite basic...but now here is the difficult part that I am having trouble with. I want to ALSO record the available weight each gym has for each equipment.

For example, I want to record that Gym A has `weight plates` of `2.5lbs, 5lbs, 10lbs, 25lbs, 35lbs, 45lbs and 100lbs`....while Gym B also has `weight plates`, but they have these ones: `5lbs, 25lbs, 45lbs`.

To make things a little more complicated...gyms are also marked as either Imperial or Metric...so Gym C has `weight plates`, but theirs are `1.25kg, 2.5kg, 5kg, 10kg, etc`.

I have considered an option where I simply just list out all of the possible options a user has (and will know what unit it is based on the gyms table) like this:

```
GYM EQUIPMENT WEIGHT
----------------------
id   GymId    EquipmentId    Weight
1    1        3              2.5
2    1        3              5
3    1        3              10
4    1        3              25
5    1        3              35
6    1        3              45
7    2        3              5
8    2        3              25
9    2        3              45
.......
```

I am really not sure how to start with this type of information. I would be open to a No-SQL solution as well if this would be more ideal...but I less familiar with this and regardless, have not been able to come up with a scalable idea.

Does anybody have any feedback, or better yet, better ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly - then I don't think your initial 3 tables hold enough information to be able to handle the Weights issue?

I think that there are 2 easyish ways of handling this either

1. Add Weight column to the Equipment table (defaults to 0 for non weights)
2. Have an (optional) One to Many link from Equipment to a Weight Plates table.

Option A - your tables might look like this :

```
EQUIPMENT
-----------------
id   Name          Weight
1    Bench         0
2    Box           0
3    Weight Plate  2.5
4    Dumbbells     0
5    Weight Plate  5
6    Weight Plate  10
7    Weight Plate  20

GYM EQUIPMENT
-----------------
id   GymId    EquipmentId    Available
1    1        3              10
2    1        5              10
3    1        6              4
4    1        7              4
```

Then you would be able to work out that Gym 1 has 10 x 2.5, 10 * 5, 4 * 10 & 4*20 weight plates.

Option B - your tables might look like this :

```
EQUIPMENT
-----------------
id   Name          
1    Bench         
2    Box           
3    Weight Plate  
4    Dumbbells     

WEIGHT PLATES
-----------------
id   Weight
1    2.5
2    5        
3    10
4    20

EQUIPMENT TO PLATES
-----------------
id equipment_id   Weight_id  Available
1  3              1          10
2  3              2          10
3  3              3          4
4  3              4          4
```

And your Gym Equipment table like this :

```
GYM EQUIPMENT
-----------------
id   GymId    EquipmentId    WeightId   Available
1    1        3              1          4
2    1        3              2          4
3    1        3              3          4
4    1        3              4          4
```

Then you would be able to work out that Gym 1 has 4 x 2.5, 4 * 5, 4 * 10 & 4*20 weight plates. (Out of a total of 10 x 2.5, 10 * 5, 4 * 10 & 4*20)

For Imperial to Metric - I would treat this as either completely separate items (e.g. a 2.5KG plate is *not* a 5LB plate) - or as a display issue and convert the details with a formula after the fact.
e.g :

```
WEIGHT PLATES
-----------------
id   Weight  Metric?
1    2.5     true
2    5       true
3    10      true
4    20      true
5    5       false
6    10      false
7    20      false
8    40      false
```

PS - ((very) rough approximations of Imperial weights!)

Comment: I can see some positives from both of these suggestions...I'm not sure why the 'EQUIPMENT TO PLATES' table is necessary in the second example. I am thinking about your solutions right now. I'll get back to you very soon.

Comment: You could definitely combine EQUIPMENT TO PLATES & WEIGHT PLATES tables!!

Comment: I did not really specify this  very well in my original question...but I am also needing to use this for machines as well. I don't think Answer A is the right way to go as it is repeating many times...

For Answer B, I think it can be in the right direction, but I am running into an issue in my head with machines where there may be many different weight possibilities. The same machine in two different manufacturers could have different increments. That means I would need to basically write down all numbers in the WEIGHT PLATES table that there could possible be.

Comment: I would also need a table for each new machine then (unless I just have one 'machine' weight possibility table)

Comment: Perhaps for Machines a range of weights might be more appropriate? So a Min/Max column? Might that be a better alternative?

Comment: I am going to use this as a model very closely, and only update it slightly for my needs, but this was pretty good. Thanks for the ideas.